# NGINX not proxying to the right server?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

So, I have set up a reverse proxy server and it does it fine for one domain (webmin.norxxxxx.com), but I'm also trying to make a proxy to another IP on the domain norwhales.com, but every time I go to https://norxxxxxx.com (HTTP not set up yet), it's acting like the host was webmin.norxxxxxx.com. (I know about the SSL Certs, it's going to be fixed once this is fixed.) Here is my config:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
  include    /usr/local/nginx/conf/mime.types;
  index    index.html index.htm index.php;

  default_type application/octet-stream;
  log_format   main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
    '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log   logs/access.log  main;
  sendfile     on;
  tcp_nopush   on;
  server_names_hash_bucket_size 128; # this seems to be required for some vhosts

server {
    listen       91.134.231.xx:80;
    server_name  webmin.norxxxxx.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log ;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;

    ## send request back to apache1 ##
    location / {
     proxy_pass  http://[2a06:e881:xxxx:xxx::1337];
     proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_buffering off;
     proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
     proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
}
## HTTPS

server {
    listen       91.134.231.xx:443;
    server_name  webmin.norxxxxx.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log ;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    ssl    on;
    ssl_certificate    /etc/webmin/miniserv.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key   /etc/webmin/miniserv.pem;
    ## send request back to apache1 ##
    location / {
     proxy_pass  https://[2a06:e881:xxxx:xxx::1337];
     proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_buffering off;
     proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
     proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}}
server {
    listen       91.134.231.xx:443;
    server_name  norxxxxx.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log ;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    ssl    on;
    ssl_certificate    /etc/webmin/miniserv.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key   /etc/webmin/miniserv.pem;
    location / {
     proxy_pass  https://[2a06:e881:xxxx:xxx::8];
     proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_buffering off;
     proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
     proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
}
##
}
#RTMP
rtmp {
        server {
                listen 1935;
                chunk_size 4096;

                application live {
                        live on;
                        record off;
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: What happends if you are creating two separate virtualhost instead?

Comment: Isn't each server { } thing one virtual host?

Comment: Turn on debug mode (just add debug after your error.log) and you will see what nginx does to process the request.

Comment: This compile of nginx does not have debugging mode feature on though, but there would be no point as I already know what it is doing.

Comment: `Yo`. Your site appears to be working correctly. What is the problem you are having?

Comment: It seems to be working fine now for HTTP, but not for HTTPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Turns out nginx bugged out, and a server restart fixed it. Silly me who didn't try this the first time.